# Calculating time space complexity in lazily evaluated languages

Tags: lazy-evaluation

Can anyone tell me how does one go about calculating the time space complexity of lazily evaluated languages?. I heard its difficult, but I would like to give it a try.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

At least for the case of data structures (I dare wager that generalises to vanilla code), you will find information in [Okasaki's "Purely functional data structures](http://scholar.google.de/scholar?cluster=624491365530207322). Other [papers from him](http://scholar.google.de/scholar?q=c+okasaki+lazy) might be valuable to your undertaking, too.